# Program compiles but does not run

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

This is an assignment i have to complete.

Can someone lead me in the right direction?

The program compiles but wont run correctly.

The error is InputMissmatch exception.

Comment: "*The error is InputMissmatch exception.*" => The exception should point you to the line that throws the exception. That should help you narrow the scope of your investigation.

Comment: What input you are giving? are you giving input as A, B, C or 0,1,2 etc?

Comment: now is a good time to familiarize yourself with your debugger.

Comment: Without reading the code, if you're getting InputMissmatch, then this means you're entering something from the keyboard that is different to the type of variable you're entering the information in. For example entering a character in an int field.

Comment: I am trying to get the user to input A,S,M,D,O or E as their choice, and then the if-statements should do the rest?

Comment: now is a good time to familiarize yourself with the different primitives.

Comment: Hint: You're asking the user to enter a letter, yet your first variable assignment from the scanner is assigning to a type "float".

Comment: if you want the user to enter the letters you mentioned, then change from the float type to a type that accepts letters, for example String

Comment: You ask the user to enter a letter, and read the letter using nextFloat(). Isn't it obvious that it will lead to an exception?

Comment: I am still learning java fully so forgive me

Comment: Also- maybe just get one input and check which input is it, rather than getting all these varables assigned to.

Comment: You should perform a little more diagnosis for this kind of question. Give us the whole stack trace of the exception, and tell us what the values of the various variables are at the point where it occured, as well as what the input being processed was.

Comment: Also, consider simplifying your code samples to isolate your error. I.e. try removing any and all code until all you have is what's needed to produce the error for a given input.

Comment: Okay thank you for all the suggestions, and tips.  I am working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are entering a letter into a float field.
In your program you're asking the user to enter a float:

```
A = hope.nextFloat();
```

But if you enter the letter "A", you're going to get an exception because "A" is not a float, it's a string.

A simpler way to solve your problem is instead of having all the choices fields, you just read the input the user enters from the scanner like:

```
String choice = hope.next();
```

Next in the if statement, you check if the value from the string choice is equal to a specific letter, for example

```
if (choice.equals("A")) {
        number4 = (number1 + number2 + number3);
        System.out.printf("Your results are:" + (number4));
    }
```

And you can do the same thing for the other choices you have.

Comment: I did this, and edited the code.  Program works great now.  A simple fix really that i should of realized.  I am still learning and was thinking to much into what i had to do.  Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The error you are getting means that you are trying to use some kind of data as another one, in your case, you are probably trying to use a String as a float.

When using any of the **next** methods in the Scanner class you should first be sure that there's an appropiate input from the user.

In order to do so, you need to use the **has** methods.

Your problem is that you are not checking wether the input is a correct float or not before using your Scanner.nextFloat();

You should do something like this:

```
if (hope.hasNextFloat())
{
    // Code to execute when you have a proper float, 
    // which you can retrieve with hope.nextFloat()
}
else
{ 
    // Code to execute when the user input is not a float
    // Here you should treat it properly, maybe asking for new input
}
```

That should be enough to point you in the right direction.

Also, check the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) api documentation for further details.

**EDIT**

Also, you are asking the user to input characters (or strings): "A", "B", etc..., but you are trying to compare them with a float. That's wrong, you should compare them with a string or character, like this:

```
if (hope.hasNextString())
{
   if (hope.nextString().equals("A"))
   {
       // Code for option "A"
   }
   else if (hope.nextString().equals("B"))
   {
       // Code for option "B"
   }
   else ...
}
```

You could use a switch there, but it seems that you are not yet very fammiliar with java, so I'll leave it for another time.